# PHP SOAP client fatal error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am having trouble run my PHP SOAP client on my machine at work.
This is my PHP SOAP client:

```
    <?php

$params=array("SendMessageRequest" => 
    array( "GsbEnvelope" =>  
        array( "MessageHeader" => 
            array("SenderId" => "000000001",
                "ServiceId" => "000000002",
                "MessageId" => "833362f-063f-11e2-892e-0802200c9a62",
                "SenderTimeStamp" => "2013-12-03T14:39"),
                "Content" => array("MimeType" =>"application/xml","Data" =>"Nesto"))));

$client = new SoapClient("GSBService.wsdl", array(
                            "trace"=>1,
                            "exceptions"=>0,
                            "cache_wsdl" => 0));

print_r( $client->sendMessage($params));

echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
echo "<p>Debug:".soapDebug($client)."</p>";
  ?>
```

this is WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="GSBService"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.apis-it.hr/umu/2013/services/GSBService"
    xmlns:umu="http://www.apis-it.hr/umu/2013/services/GSBService"
    xmlns:gsb="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">

  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.apis-it.hr/umu/2013/services/GSBService">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb" schemaLocation="../schema/GSBSchema.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="SendMessageRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="gsb:SendMessageRequest" name="request"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SendMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="gsb:SendMessageResponse" name="response"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="EchoRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="gsb:EchoRequest" name="request" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="EchoResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="gsb:EchoResponse" name="response" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="GSBServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="sendMessage">
      <wsdl:input message="umu:SendMessageRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="umu:SendMessageResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="echo">
        <wsdl:input message="umu:EchoRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="umu:EchoResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="GSBService" type="umu:GSBServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sendMessage">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.apis-it.hr/umu/2013/services/GSBService/sendMessage"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="echo">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.apis-it.hr/umu/2013/services/GSBService/echo"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="GSBService">
    <wsdl:port binding="umu:GSBService" name="GSBServicePortType">
      <soap:address location="http://www.apis-it.hr:8849/GsbService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Output is:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php on line 15

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php on line 15

Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd' in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php on line 15
```

I can easily access xmldsig-core-schema.xsd file via web browser and my administrator told me that port 80 and 443 are not blocked.

Comment: Have you tried to trace the background traffic with wireshark to see whether ther is a valid request/response?

Comment: The connection to the remote resource seems rather slow. Try setting `connection_timeout` to a larger number of seconds in your soap client params.

Comment: I don't have admin privileges to install wireshark. My company is using 2 firewalls TMG and Check Point.

Comment: I changed "connection_timeout" => 360 and even default_socket_timeout=300, but I still have same error.

Comment: I have solved this by downloading WSDL locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related with the outbound port 8585. If the port blocked in the server, the server can't be able to access the public internet through the port. So, allow the port to access the public internet by unblocking it. It is only the solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by enabling function "libxml_disable_entity_loader" in php.ini

> Note: You must also call libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) somewhere in your application's startup script to enable loading of external XML entities.